# Latency when loading html content with FOSJsRoutingBundle and Ajax (route parameter {id})

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, latency

I am using [FOSjSrouting](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#generating-uris) in my **symfony2.7** project.

I have this `html.twig` view code:

```
<table>
<!--table header code ...etc... -->
  <tbody>
    {% for currentData in arrayData %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ currentData.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.order}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.category}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.location}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.price}}</td>
        <td>
          <a><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs showDetail" href="{{ path('detailsData', {'idData': currentData.idData }) }}">Show Detail</button></a> <!-- to open dialog tag through Ajax for each lines -->
          <a href="{{ path('editData', {'idData': currentData.idData }) }}"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</button></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- the dialog window to load detail content -->
<dialog id="window"></dialog>

<!-- javascript to open and close dialog window -->
<script>
  (function() {
    var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
    var showButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('showDetail');
    var showDialog = function() {
      console.log(this);
      dialog.show();
      dialog.load(Routing.generate('detailsData', {'idData': currentData.idData }) }})
    };
    var i, len = showButtons.length;
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        showButtons[i].onclick = showDialog;
    }
    document.getElementById('exit').onclick = function() {
      dialog.close();
    };
  })();
</script>
```

As you can see, foreach data I want to display, I have a detail button. This detail button refers to another page which displays linked data to the current data I clicked on.

This the route for the detail view (respecting the FOSjSrouting needs):

```
detailData:
    pattern:  /manage/order/detail/{idData}
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceMyBundle:MyController:detailData }
    requirements:
    methods: GET
    options:
        expose: true
```

The **purpose** is to **load** via *Ajax*, *jQuery*, *FOSjSrouting* the linked datas in the `dialog` tag with the `id="window"` to the `currentData.idData`.

But when I click on the detail button, I have this error (in my browser console):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: **currentData** is not defined

I understand that I need to take care about the `{id}` **parameter of my route**.

How can I load the page that the detail button refers to and displays the right linked data through ajax with my current `script` (at the end of my html code)?

---

EDIT

I add this code in javascript at the end of my **script tag** in my `html.twig` view, it allows me to display the datas I want in my dialog tag:

```
$('.showDetail').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'url': Routing.generate('detailsData', {'idData': $(this).val()}),
        'cache' : false,
        'success': function(loadDetail) {
            $('#window').html(loadDetail);
        }
    });
  });
```

The problem occured is that I have a **latency** to display the **dialog tag**, and just **before** displaying the current data I want, the **last one** I clicked on **are displaying before for a few second**, and then my current data I want is display later.

Maybe It's a cache problem?

Moreover, the first time I click on the detailButton, the dialog is displaying empty, then after (latency), the data are displaying.

How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the variable is not defined in javascript. You have to insert curly brackets to let twig translate the twig variable into the corresponding value like this:

```
{'idData': {{currentData.idData}} }
```

Unfortunately therefor it has to be in the for loop as well - so it might be better to safe the value in an data attribute and read it by using javascript.

You could also use the already populated `href` attribute like this (using jQuery as you said you are doing):

```
dialog.load($(this).attr('href'))
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately, doing like this returns me this error `Uncaught TypeError: dialog.load is not a function` when I click on a **detailButton**. 
See my edit, I have almost found a solution, but I have a latency when I'm trying to display the dialog tag, and sometimes before displaying the right datas, the last datas I clicked on are displaying just before the current data I want to display.